# NHibernate, fetch entity and eager load part of child collection

Tags: nhibernate, eager-loading

I've come unstuck on how to do this:

I have a country entity. A country has zero or more facts. A fact has property called Year.

How can I load a Country entity by its name and eagerly fetch all its facts from a given year, e.g. 2011 (but not load all the other facts)? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is possible using filtering but it's not a good idea because it violates separation of concerns: your domain model should not be used to present a special view of the data.

Two possibly better options:

1. Fetch all the facts and filter them by year using an extension method on `IEnumerable<Fact>`. I would pick this option unless I had a measurable performance issue.
2. Create a view class that encapsulates the result set. You can construct the two queries to retrieve the Country and Facts for a year using `Future` so that it only requires one trip to the database.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I agree that filtering isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible by using filters in nHibernate. Start out by reading this previous StackOverflow question:

[NHibernate - Retrieve parent / children with criteria applied only to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016767/nhibernate-retrieve-parent-children-with-criteria-applied-only-to-children)

And also have a look at the nHibernate documentation for more reference:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
 var query = session.QueryOver<Country>()
        .Fetch(c => c.Facts)
        .Eager()
        .TransformUsing(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .Future();
    session.QueryOver<Facts>()
        .Where(f => f.Year == 2011)
        .Future();
    var country = query.List().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi Mariusz, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to compile? "Method, delegate or event is expected." Also, the expression f => f.Year == 2011 does not compile as "f" is not understood.

Comment: OK - the call to Eager should be a call to a property, not a method. But the Where() clause doesn't compile becase f is Country, not Fact

Comment: Mariusz, thanks for this. This runs two queries in one db hit but the returned result contains all facts, not just those from 2011.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** 
I have *not* solved this. The below HQL only works when facts are present. If there are no facts for a given year then the result is null. I think the correct solution, given my context, is to treat Fact as an aggregate root and issue two queries using Future().

**Original post**

I have solved this using HQL:

```
var country = Session.CreateQuery("from Country country left join fetch country.Facts as Facts where Facts.Year in (:years) and country.Name = :name ");
country.SetParameter("name", name);
country.SetParameterList("years", new List<int>() {2012, 2011});
```

Thanks for the other suggestions. I would be interested in a non-HQL solution to the problem, but this solves it well.